# Window.parent.PostMessage works in reverse order in firefox

Tags: firefox, postmessage

I have 3 postmessage calls from my iframe to the parent window. These 3 are executed in reverse in firefox. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use more than one `postMessage` within a single execution of JavaScript in Firefox, they are not processed by the browser until the execution has completed, and, as far as I can tell, Firefox always processes these last-in-first-out rather than first-in-first-out.

`setTimeout` is one way to order your `postMessage` calls, e.g. using a `postMessage` wrapper:

```
function postMessage(otherWindow, message, targetOrigin, transfer) {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
        },
        0
    );
}
```

This defers all your `postMessage` calls to subsequent executions of JavaScript that the browser will execute in order.